# Chameleon harpoon tongue - plausable or not?

Tags: biology, anatomy, bio-mechanics

My future “chameleons” have evolved a harpoon-like tongue as an adaptation for catching larger prey as their own body size has gotten significantly larger over the milions of years. I drew a simple model of said tongue, but I’m not sure whether it’s plausable. [image]

Comment: I would suggest looking up snail love darts. Some are used for delivering toxins to prey.

Comment: Hi, Lizardsaurus. Just to make a point, the [help/on-topic] states, "Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is a site for designers, writers, artists, gamers and enthusiasts to get help creating imaginary worlds." In other words, it's your imaginary world, so it's as plausible as you want it to be. Further, you didn't read the wiki for the [tag:reality-check] tag, because it doesn't mean what you think it means. Here's the summary from the  [help/on-topic], "Provide the relevant details of your world and a situation and we will make sure it remains internally consistent." So I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, chameleons unfurl their tongues forward faster than a jet plane and the prey sticks to their tongue.
To have a harpoon-like tongue, they need something sharp at the end of their tongue which pierces the prey's body and does not come out.

One can think like this:

- Their are sets of bones like sharp barbs at the end of the tongue
  (similar to a hand-thrown harpoon).
- There is a nail-like bone at the end of the tongue which pierces the
  prey's body and then the end of tongue swells like dog's bulbis
  glandis swells during mating or kangaroo's nipples swell in the mouth
  of new born baby.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly feasible, actually. Especially if the harpoon is venemous. Certain species of sea snails have developed a harpoon-esque modified radula tooth and a venom gland to attack and paralyze prey. Chameleons evolving a similar attachment is definitely feasible.

[Here's a wikipedia article on them.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_snail)